# Unable to update google spreadsheet from data entered in sidebar

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I have created sidebar through google script HTML and when I am trying to append the data entered in Sidebar to Active Google Spreadsheet and I am unable to trace where the code is failing to append the entered data. I am attaching my HTML code and gs code. Request to let me know where my code went wrong.
Also I would like to create a drop down for dependency field which needs to take input from spreadsheet, I have no idea about this can anyone help with the literature. Thank you in advance

```
function SideBar() {

  var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SideBar')
  var html= template.evaluate();
  html.setTitle("New Task");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Task Manager")
  .addItem("Add New Task","SideBar")
  .addToUi();
  //.addItem("Update Task","SideBar")
  //.addToUi();
  //.addItem("Re-assign Task", "SideBar")
  //.addToUi();
  ui.showSidebar(html);
  }

function appendData(data){

  //var url= '1S64cYsfHEcddmOfXNfAO6VaCQ9LIFPylx8Sj_6h70e4';
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Task");
  var log= ws.appendRow([data.Task,
                data.TaskDescription,
                data.AssignedTo,
                data.StartDate,
                data.EndDate,
                data.PriorityType,
                data.Dependency]);
  Logger.log(log);

}
```

/* HTML File code below */

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>
          <input id="Task" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Task">Task</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">description</i>
          <input id="TaskDescription" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="TaskDescription">Task Description</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
          <input id="AssignedTo" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="AssignedTo">Assigned To </label>

          <!--div class="dropdown-content">
                 <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
                 <a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
            </div-->            
        </div>

     <div class="input-field col s6">
          <!--i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i-->
          <input id="StartDate" type="date" class="validate">
          <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label>  
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <!--i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i-->
          <input id="EndDate" type="date" class="validate">
          <label for="EndDate">End Date </label>
          </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <!--i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i-->
          <input id="PriorityType" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="PriorityType">Priority Type </label>        
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <!--i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i-->
          <input id="Dependency" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Dependency">Dependency </label>         
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
         <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Assign
           <input id="btn">
           <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
       </div> 


      </div>   
      </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <script>

      var Task = document.getElementById("Task");
      var TaskDescription = document.getElementById("TaskDescription");
      var AssignedTo = document.getElementById("AssignedTo");
      var StartDate = document.getElementById("StartDate");
      var EndDate = document.getElementById("EndDate");
      var PriorityType = document.getElementById("PriorityType");
      var Dependency = document.getElementById("Dependency");-->

      document.getElementbyId("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);

      function addRecord(data){
           var data= {
           Task:Task.value,
           TaskDescription:TaskDescription.value,
           AssignedTo:AssignedTo.value,
           StartDate:StartDate.value,
           EndDate:EndDate.value,
           PriorityType:PriorityType.value,
           Dependency:Dependency.value
           };
           google.script.run.appendData(data);
      }

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code a lot.  There  were several client side errors in it.  I recommend you spend more time learning about using  your browsers developer tools.  Especially the console.log.

You will probably want to bring some of your styling back in I'd do it slowly so you don't get lost again.

Any way this works now with a similar addRecord function.

Google Script:

```
function ShowDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq7');
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(userInterface);
  }

function appendData(data){
  Logger.log(data);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Task").appendRow([data.text]);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" value="Assign" onClick="addRecord();" />
      <script>
      function addRecord(){
        var t=document.getElementById('txt').value;
        var data={text:t};
        console.log(data);
        google.script.run.appendData(data);
      }
      console.log('My Code')
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This error took a while to find.  Can you see where it is?

`document.getElementbyId("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);`

Comment: Hi , Thank you for response @Cooper. I already used google.script.run.appendData(data) [function name] to communicate with server. Also tried by activating drive API,but still I am unable to update the data in excel

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are not the same

Comment: I think my question clearly mentions that. Thank you

Comment: I'm referring to you comment above where you clearly say `still I am unable to update the data in excel`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cooper. Your script has helped me and finally it is working when I change the input button outside div and gave Onclick run function directly. Still I am not sure why Event Listener command did not work.
The Codes are as follows:
G code:

```
   function onOpen() {
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SideBarBackUp');
      userInterface.setTitle('New Task');
      var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.showSidebar(userInterface);
      ui.createMenu("Task Manager")
      .addItem("Add New Task","SideBar")
      .addToUi();
      }

    function appendData1(data){
      Logger.log(data);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Task").appendRow([data.txt,data.dxt,data.axt,data.sxt,data.ext,data.pxt,data.yxt]);
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>
          <input id="Task" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Task">Task</label>
        </div>         

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">description</i>
          <input id="TaskDescription" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="TaskDescription">Task Description</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
          <input id="AssignedTo" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="AssignedTo">Assigned To </label>         
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="StartDate" type="date" class="validate">
          <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label>  
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">   
          <input id="EndDate" type="date" class="validate">
          <label for="EndDate">End Date</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="PriorityType" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="PriorityType">Priority Type </label>        
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="Dependency" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Dependency">Dependency </label>         
        </div>
</div>
</div>       
       <input id=btn type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" value="Assign" onClick="addRecord();" />

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <script>

     // document.getElementbyId('btn').addEventListener('click', addRecord();)

     function addRecord(data){
          var t= document.getElementById('Task').value;
          var d= document.getElementById('TaskDescription').value;
          var a= document.getElementById('AssignedTo').value;
          var s= document.getElementById('StartDate').value;
          var e= document.getElementById('EndDate').value;
          var p= document.getElementById('PriorityType').value;
          var y= document.getElementById('Dependency').value;
          var data={txt:t,dxt:d,axt:a,sxt:s,ext:e,pxt:p,yxt:y};
          console.log(data);
        google.script.run.appendData1(data);
         }
      console.log('My Code')


      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Thank you once again for patience response and as a newbie to coding I would surely work more on my coding skills.

Comment: The event listener function did not work probably because as @Cooper spotted. "document.getElementbyId is not a function"... the function you are looking for is `document.getElementById()` notice the difference?

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you